# BLE - Smartphone not save the pairing of my device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working with my custom APP bluetooth and my device BLE, I have some problems. The my phone is Samsung A8 and I install the my app. If I not use the pairing with my device the APP it works very well. I can turn on/off led of my device. If I use the pairing, I click on Connect, but I not can turn on/off the led. The my smartphone works only 1 times, It only works once, after exiting and returning from the app. If I want to reconnect I will require the paired.

I write this in my code:

```
private void getpaireddevices(){
    Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices();
    if(devicesArray.size() > 0) {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : devicesArray) {
            device.getName();
            device.getAddress();
        }
    }
}
```

Please Help!!

Comment: Hi. Can you please explain more detailed exactly what doesn't work? Which operations fail and which kind of error messages do you get (if any)?

Comment: Hi Emil. I using a device of Texas Instruments. In this device, it possible enable/disable the pairing. If I disable the pairing, the my app it works very well. If I enable the pairing, the my app not work, but with another APPs it works. When I open the APP, it requires the paired, i enter the code..but not communicate.